# Let's start coding on the search page

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

First, let's [do some random search](/search?q=aaa+bbb). You'll be welcomed by a line of code:

[image: bug]

MSE is not the only place to see this. It seems to be network-wide.

Is it a bug or a feature?

Comment: Looks like the function that is supposed to return the string to be displayed at that place is returning itself.

Comment: Users can now code their own search. It is a feature.

Comment: **desktop website only**. Nothing wrong on mobile web.

Comment: @rene Your comment is best served with tag [status-bydesign]

Comment: I can't reproduce it on any browser.

Comment: @DonaldDuck Patched speedly. Waiting for [meta-tag:status-completed]

Comment: Looks like it's really patched. The current rev on 2018.2.8.28856 no longer contains the bug.

Comment: Some hours ago when you posted this I could see this behavior. Now it appears to be "gone"

Comment: Yeah I saw the big red question mark come up in my search results too.

Comment: @Joe glad to see you finally got diamond here! :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Got frustrated enough with a few limitations that I finally gave in and requested it.

Comment: @Joe cheers, must admit it fits you well. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard are you trying to make a *diamonds* and *friends* reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also saw this feature you mention the moment you posted this. However, seems that currently this has been "corrected" (also network-wide, tested on Chrome and FF):

[image]